# An arctangent series

Tags: fourier-series

We know that the arctan series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\arctan \left( {\frac{{2{a^2}}}{{{n^2}}}} \right)} $ exist closed form, see
[enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128181/an-arctan-series-with-a-parameter-sum-n-1-infty-arctan-left-frac2a2n).
Similarly, my question is that the arctan series of the form
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\arctan \left( {\frac{1}
{{{n^p}}}} \right)}}
{{{n^q}}}}=? ,\;p + q \geqslant 2.$$ 
It exist closed form?